# Problem with using Glossaries package

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to use the glossaries package for Latex. I have a TexLive 2014 installation on Windows 7.

The CTAN page on glossaries page [http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries][1] says that the package is contained in TexLive. But when I try to use the package, I get an error saying  LaTeX Error: File `glossaries.sty' not found.

I tried using TexLive manager, but the Glossaries package is not listed here. I couldn't find the glossaries package anywhere in the Texlive folder.

I downloaded the zip file of the glossaries package into my texlive\2014\texmf-dist\tex\latex folder, and ran the installer file (glossaries.ins) from commandline. Now I can see the glossaries.sty in this folder, but I'm still getting the same error.

Is there anything else I need to do to activate the glossaries package?

Comment: You shouldn't install manually files in the texmf-dist. This will only confuse the texlive manager. Better use on the command line `tlmgr install glossaries`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! After manually installing a package you have to run `mktexlsr`. However, it's much better following Ulrike's advice.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)